# GLSL min/max nomarlization

Tags: web, glsl

Is there a built in GLSL function for [Min/Max Normalization](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_is_min-max_normalization)? It seems so useful for so many things, but I can't seem to find one.

```
magicfunction(input, min, max); //=> normalized float
magicfunction(0.3, 0.1, 0.4);   //=> 0.66667
```

Does such a thing exist? Or should I copy my own math utility function into every one of my shaders?

Comment: "*Or should I copy my own math utility function into every one of my shaders?*" Why should you have to copy it? There's a reason that `glShaderSource` takes *multiple* strings.

Comment: [Where I come from](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Mathf.InverseLerp.html) we call this "InverseLerp".

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found it in [`smoothstep(min, max, input)`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothstep) which is sort of an odd name, but it appears to do what I want.

Comment: `smoothstep` does a cubic Hermite interpolation, whereas the link you post seems to specify a linear interpolation...

Comment: @ChrisDodd Is there a built function that does the same without the curving?